# M2P DMA transfer with trigger from a different peripheral

Tags: stm32, timer, dma

The microcontroller on my board is STM32F429IGT6 and I want to use a timer as a trigger of a DMA -e.g. HTIM_SOUND_SAMPLER- and transfer my data from an array to CCP of another timer -e.g. HTIM_SOUND_DC_MAKER-.

```
HAL_DMA_Start(HTIM_SOUND_SAMPLER.hdma[TIM_DMA_ID_UPDATE], (uint32_t)dual_sine_12bit, (uint32_t)&HTIM_SOUND_DC_MAKER.Instance->CCR1, 32);

/* Enable the TIM Update DMA request */
__HAL_TIM_ENABLE_DMA(&HTIM_SOUND_SAMPLER, TIM_DMA_UPDATE);
```

Consider **htim2** as **HTIM_SOUND_DC_MAKER**.

When I define **htim8** as **HTIM_SOUND_SAMPLER** there will be no problem. 
But when I change **HTIM_SOUND_SAMPLER** to **htim3** it doesn't work as I expect.
The reason I do this is that I want to use DMA1 so I have to use htim3 instead of htim8.

Is there anything I missed? why does it happen?
Is it possible to use one peripheral as the trigger and another one as the destination or source? If not, then why when I use htim8, it is possible?

Comment: no I saw it. It's different.

Comment: Ok, close vote retracted

Comment: So you've posted some code that stops working when some other code, which is not shown, changes. Please include **ALL** relevant code and definitions. And check the usual suspects, `RCC->APB1ENR`, DMA channel and stream selection, and all relevant registers using the reference manual.

Answer (score 0):

DMA requests from each peripheral are hardwired to either DMA1 or DMA2, see the *request mapping* tables in the *DMA functional description* of the reference manual.

So a request *from* `TIM1` or `TIM8` can trigger a copy operation only in DMA2, other timers can only trigger DMA1.

While DMA2 transfers can reach any peripheral, the peripheral addresses on DMA1 are restricted to the APB1 bus.

A request from `TIM8` can trigger a stream on DMA2, which is able to copy something to/from the registers of `TIM3`, but it doesn't work the other way round, because `TIM3` can only trigger a stream on DMA1, which is not able to reach out to TIM8, which is on APB2. DMA1 can only access timers 2 to 7.

Comment: sorry my mistake. I edited my question.